# Shopping cart Active Record Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to implement a shopping cart within a Rails application. For this, I am trying to glue together these models:

`user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cart_contents
end
```

`cart_content.rb`:

```
class CartContent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :product
end
```

`product.rb`

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
end
```

To test if this arrangement is working, I tried this in the console:

```
irb(main):006:0> cc = CartContent.new
=> 
#<CartContent:0x000055679d802a28
...

irb(main):008:0> cc.user = User.find(1)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM [...]
=> #<User id: 1, email: "mail@example.com", ...

irb(main):010:0> cc.product = Product.find(1)
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM [...]                                                                      
/[...]/activemodel-7.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute.rb:211:
in `with_value_from_database': can't write unknown attribute `cart_content_id` (ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError)
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to indicate a relationship to `cart_content` in `product.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me.

`product.rb`

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :cart_content
end
```

`cart_content.rb`

```
class CartContent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end
```

`user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cart_contents
  has_many :products, through: :cart_contents # for convenience
end
```

Rails no longer expects a `cart_content_id` column on `Product` and the following commands all work in the console:

```
user = User.first
product = Product.first
cc = CartContent.new
cc.user = user
cc.product = product
cc.save

User.first.products # returns products currently in cart
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution: you may want your `CartContent` to `belongs_to :product`.

```
class CartContent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :product # change this to belongs_to
end

cc.product = Product.find(1)

# .. can't write unknown attribute `cart_content_id` (ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError)
```

`has_one` will expect your `products` table to have a `cart_content_id` column.

See guide section [2.7 Choosing Between belongs_to and has_one](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one)

Comment: This was part of the fix, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to build relations between your models. As mentioned by Jared in [this link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one) for the foreign key to exist, you need to specify a belongs_to constraint.

> The distinction is in where you place the foreign key (it goes on the table for the class declaring the belongs_to association)

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart_content
end
```

If you also want to access all Products for User you can go for below, but you probably don't need a `through` relation.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cart_contents
  has_many :products, through: :cart_contents
end
```

Then your Product model would look like this

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart_content
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the has_many through: relationship, that's certainly convenient.